# Trying to get a Dark overlay on my Bootstrap Carousel Image/Video

Tags: html, css, overlay, bootstrap-5

I've been putting trying to get a dark overlay on an image/video on my bootstrap 5 site, but every time I do so, it also puts it over the text? My Code is as follows

```css
.drk:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item drk active">
      <video class="d-block img-fluid w-100" preload muted autoplay loop>
              <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>Push your boundaries. Expand your brand.</h1>
        <h3>You don’t have to own a business or logo to have a brand. Who are you and what do you do? What are you passionate about? What talents do you have? What is <i>your</i> brand?</h3>
        <h3>At Free Solo Studios we are just as passionate about you and your brand as we are of our own, and we don’t succeed until you do.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've followed a few tutorial's on YT but I must be doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Result:

[image: My Results]

How it should look like:

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: I am not good with BS but i guess you should have ".drk:after" styles on ".carousel-caption" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index` in `.carousel-caption` more than overlay

```css
.drk:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item drk active"> 
    
      <video class="d-block img-fluid w-100" preload muted autoplay loop>
         <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>Push your boundaries. Expand your brand.</h1>
        <h3>You don’t have to own a business or logo to have a brand. Who are you and what do you do? What are you passionate about? What talents do you have? What is <i>your</i> brand?</h3>
        <h3>At Free Solo Studios we are just as passionate about you and your brand as we are of our own, and we don’t succeed until you do.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```